# Java loop not iterating

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I am getting an IndexOutOfBounds error out of this code:

```
Log.w("aa", "line size: " + line.getSize());
for ( a = line.getSize() - 1; a >= 0; a--);
   test(a, line);   
}

public void test(int a, LineCreator line){
   Log.w("AA", "a equals: " + a);
   int test = line.getSquare(a);
}
```

> 06-17 21:31:42.169      421-442/com.Nuotta W/aa﹕ line size: 3
>
> 06-17 21:31:42.169      421-442/com.Nuotta W/AA﹕ a equals: -1

The line size that it gets is 3. But it gives out a -1.

LineCreator is an object of mine. It has very simple methods getSize which just returns Array.length and getSquare(x) which returns ArrayList.get(x) They work in every other place but not here.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your `for` loop; it's currently the body of your `for` loop.

Comment: and you may be also missing the opening { for the first loop.

Comment: I really wish that this was a compilation warning/error and force a body to be put into brackets or something.  An accidental typing error here could cause significant heartache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( a = line.getSize() - 1; a >= 0; a--);
    test(a, line);   
}
```

You have a semicolon at the end of your for loop.

What happens is that the for loop loops but never executes `test`. So `a` is set to -1 through the iterations then `test` is called.

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the for loop and it will work.

Comment: @Molehole It does display a warning because it isn't an error. Also, if an answer helps you then you can mark it as accepted to help future visitors to the site.

Comment: @Molehole If you can set your IDE to automatically add in braces around loop bodies, this kind of thing gets caught surprisingly fast, as you end up with braces surrounding a `;`, and it's quite difficult to miss. It becomes pretty much impossible to miss if you can do that and enable a warning about empty statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon `;` after the `for` statement, which means that the *body* of the `for`  is *empty*. So, this loop will iterate until the condition is `false`. When the condition is false, `a` will be `-1`. And then, outside the `for` loop, you are calling to the `test` method, with the following arguments:

```
test(-1, line);
```

which will lead into the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Notice that you can access to `a` outside the `for` because you have declared it *outside* the loop, making it accessible even after the loop has finished.

In order to visualize it better, your code is equivalent to:

```
for ( a = line.getSize() - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
    // empty
}

test(a, line);    // here 'a' will be -1
```